# Jmeter-Get epoch timestamp AT midnight using time functions

Tags: jmeter

Does anyone know how to get epoch timestamp AT midnight using the jmeter.time functions? I see answers/questions for formatting. But I need the epoch time for the current date at midnight. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using any [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy language and/or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy). The relevant code would be something like:

```
new Date().clearTime().getTime()
```

[image: JMeter Get Today Midnight Demo]

Just in case you want another time offset:

```
def myDate = new Date()
myDate.set(hourOfDay: 5, minute: 6, second: 7)
log.info('Timestamp would be: ' + myDate.getTime())
```